# How do I convert a dataframe of strings to csv in python?

Tags: python, string, csv, glob

I have created a program that picks up names of all files in a directory using python glob package

```
import glob

path = 'D:\Movies\American and Brit Cinema'

files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.avi", recursive=True)]

for f in files:
    print(f[35:])
```

I do get my desired output:

```
The.Descendants.2011.
The.Expendables.2010.
The.Hangover.2009
The.Impossible.2012
the.invention.of.lying.2009
The.Muppets.2011.
The.Social.Network.2010
Tron.Legacy.2010
```

However, I want to take this list of movie titles and export it to a csv

When I try I get the below error-

```
    f.to_csv('EnglishMovies.docx')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

I tried converting to a list as well but I just get messy data. I just want my final csv file to have the names of all the files in my directory

Comment: In your example you just create `list` named `files` holding `str`s, how is `dataframe` tag relevant for your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `csv` module

```
import csv

with open('output.csv',  mode='w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for f in files:
        writer.writerow([f])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the `.csv` file directly and write to it.

```
with open("path_to_csv/movies.csv", "w") as fp:
    for f in files:
        fp.write(f+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `.to_csv` method, you can create a data frame and then write it to csv.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = 'D:\Movies\American and Brit Cinema'
files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.avi", recursive=True)]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Movie Names'])
df['Movie Names'] = files
df['Movie Names'] = df['Movie Names'].str[35:]
df.to_csv(path + '\EnglishMovies.csv')
```